# R how to read text file based on condition

Tags: r, read.csv

I'm a beginner in R, and I have a large txt file like this:

```
1:
123,3,2002-09-06
456,2,2005-08-13
789,4,2001-09-20
2:
123,5,2003-05-08
321,1,2004-06-15
432,3,2001-09-11
```

The line with ':' is the itemID, the following lines are UserID, Quantity and Date

I want to read it into data.frame like this:

```
itemID UserID Quantity Date
  1      123   3      2002-09-06
  1      456   2      2005-08-13  
  1      789   4      2001-09-20
  2      123   5      2003-05-08
  2      321   1      2004-06-15
  2      432   3      2001-09-11
```

Can it be achieved by using read.csv? Or how to read this file by condition?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.table()` isn't going to be able to easily read this. R expects most data data to be clean and rectangular.

You can read the data in as a bunch of lines, manipulate those lines to a more regular format, and then parse that using `read.table`. For example

```
# Read your data file
# xx <- readLines("mydatafile.txt")
# for the sake of a complete example
xx <- scan(text="1:
123,3,2002-09-06
456,2,2005-08-13
789,4,2001-09-20
2:
123,5,2003-05-08
321,1,2004-06-15
432,3,2001-09-11", what=character())
```

This reads in the lines as just strings. Then you can split into groups and append the item ID as another value to each row

```
item_group <- cumsum(grepl("\\d+:", xx))
clean_rows <- unlist(lapply(split(xx, item_group), function(x) {
    item_id = gsub(":$",",", x[1])
    paste0(item_id, x[-1])
}))
```

Then you can parse the data into a data.frame

```
read.table(text=clean_rows, sep=",", col.names=c("itemID","UserID","Quantity","Date"))
```

Comment: So if you are reading from a file you will change the scan command like so .  
    ...........................................   .    `scan( file = "tempo\\tempo.txt", what=character())`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.  It's rather manual and there's a lot to unpack in this example...

```
separator_pattern <- "^(\\d+):\\s*$"
block_text <- out <- NULL
for(line in readLines(file("~/temp/example.txt"))){
    if(grepl(separator_pattern,line)){
        if(!is.null(block_text)){
            txt <- paste(c(paste0("column",1:3,collapse = ", "), block_text), collapse="\n")
            tmp <- cbind("block" = block_no, read.csv(textConnection(txt)))
            out <- rbind(out,tmp)
        }
        block_no <- as.numeric(gsub(separator_pattern,"\\1",line))
        print(block_no)
        block_text <- character(0)
    }else{
        block_text <- c(block_text,line)
    }
}
txt <- paste(c(paste0("column",1:3,collapse = ", "), block_text), collapse="\n")
tmp <- cbind("block" = block_no, read.csv(textConnection(txt)))
out <- rbind(out,tmp)
```

Obviously this assumes that your file is located in `path.expand("~/temp/example.txt")`